# multi select check box with ng-model angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I have the below controller setup so that I can add the checked values into an array as shown below.

```js
(function (app) {
  'use strict';
  
  app.controller('SimpleArrayCtrl', ['$scope', function SimpleArrayCtrl($scope) {
    // fruits
    $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'naartjie'];
    
    // selected fruits
    $scope.selection = ['apple', 'pear'];
    
    // toggle selection for a given fruit by name
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(fruitName) {
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(fruitName);
      
      // is currently selected
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
      }
      
      // is newly selected
      else {
        $scope.selection.push(fruitName);
      }
    };
  }]);
})(angular.module('app', []));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="SimpleArrayCtrl">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>selectables</h4>
            <form class="form-group" novalidate name="test">
              <label ng-repeat="fruitName in fruits" class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFruits[]" value="{{fruitName}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(fruitName) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(fruitName)"> {{fruitName}}
              </label>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>selection</h4>
            <pre>{{selection|json}}</pre>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>inputs</h4>
            <pre>{{fruits|json}}</pre>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>form</h4>
            <pre>{{test|json}}</pre>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

What I am trying to do is bind the value of the array into the form  so that I can submit the contents of the array.

I have adding `ng-model` to my checkbox input but I only seem to be only able to return true and false to my array rather than my value

```
                <input ng-model="fruitName" type="checkbox" name="selectedFruits[]" value="{{fruitName}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(fruitName) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(fruitName)">
```

How can i bind the value of selection to the model and ensure the tick is still honoured on click so that I can submit the value of the array when I submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

ngTrueValue   (ng-true-value="")
The value to which the expression should be set when selected.

ngFalseValue  (ng-false-value="")
The value to which the expression should be set when not selected.

See example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [this](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) directive.
Worked great for me
[source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vitalets/checklist-model/master/checklist-model.js)